# Python GUI EXE меняем ссылку на сайт

Tags: python

Код написанный на python преобразовал в Exe файл.
Использовал библиотеку pywebview для вывода сайта.
У коллег сайт открывается, все нормально.
Вопрос, можно как то удаленно менять сайт, не переписывая код, коллеги открыли приложение, а там уже другой сайт.
Может есть утилиты или специальные библиотеки, подскажите варианты.

Comment: ну например можно на гугл диск залить текстовый файл, в который записать url. а программа будет считывать при запуске этот файл и url, соответственно

Comment: Ну, например сделать свой сервер, который, в зависимости от значения в его собственном локальном конфиге, будет делать *redirect* на нужный сайт. А приложение пусть просто отправляет запрос на сервер и отображает результат

Comment: Мне понравилась идея на гугл диск залить текстовый файл с url. Я не знаю как называется такая библиотека

Comment: Спасибо за идею. Реализовал свою идею через библиоетку Python-docx.
А также Python работает с текстовыми файлами.
Положил текстовый документ на сервер и теперь просто меняю сайты в документе.